# Handling key-value-pair arrays in ESB API

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are working with ESB 4.8.1 and BPS 3.5. We'd love to upgrade, but management is resistant.

The BPS returns most of its data in the form of arrays of key-value-pairs, for example

```
"variables":
    [{"name":"valid","type":"boolean","value":true,"scope":"global"},
    {"name":"processComments","value":null,"scope":"global"},
    {"name":"vesselStatus","type":"string","value":"S","scope":"global"},
    ...]
```

Some of which we need to parse into more conventional JSON, e.g.

```
"variables":{"valid":true, "vesselStatus":"S"}
```

And in many cases variable names and the formats of their values must me massaged for the UI, or specific values must be extracted for a call to the SOAP services.

There didn't seem to be any obvious iterative logic mediator, and I don't think I'd want to use it if there was, so we've been using class mediators to store most of our ESB-layer logic. Now that we've released the product and entered a maintenance cycle we want to refactor into a better process.

I say all that to ask this question: is there a "best" or "right" way to do what we're trying to do?

Comment: Do you want to convert the initial payload the following one showed by you?

Comment: That's one of the things I need to do, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at payload mediator[1] if these payloads are static, if not you could use XSLT mediator[2].

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/PayloadFactory+Mediator
[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/XSLT+Mediator